# Updating table fields with button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to update cell in my table with the data from a drop down box in that row each time the button is clicked in that row.  Each row has a drop down box and a button as you can see in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcjos.png

I'm trying to set it up so that when user selects a value from a drop down box and clicks the update button it will update value of Room column only for that row.  But I can't figure out how to get the button even working and wanted to see if anyone can help me with this.

Here is my controller:

```
def index
@students = Student.all
@first_floor = %w(1101 1102 1103 1104 1105)
@second_floor = %w(2101 2102 2103 2104)
@third_floor = %w(3101 3102 3103 3104)

@selected_room = params[:room]

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @students }
end
end
```

Here is the part of the view for the table:

```
<% @students.each do |student|%>
<tr>
<td><%= student.id %></td>
<td><%= student.n_number %></td>
<td><%= student.f_name %></td>
<td><%= student.l_name %></td>
<td><%= student.date_submit %></td>
<td><%= student.floor_pref %></td>
<td><%= @selected_room %></td>
<% form_tag do %>
<% if student.floor_pref == '1st' %>
    <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@first_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
<% end %>
<% if student.floor_pref == '2nd' %>
    <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@second_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
<% end %>
<% if student.floor_pref == '3rd' %>
    <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@third_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
<% end %>
<td><%= submit_tag 'Update' %></td>
<% end %>
<td><%= button_to 'Show', :controller => 'students', :action => 'preview', :id => student%></td>
<td><%= button_to 'Remove', student, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you want to save the room preference to database and update the table in your view, right?

Comment: No I do not want to save 'Room' to DB.  Id, N-Number, First Name, Last Name, Date and Floor Pref are part of the DB.  I just want it so that when a user selects a room from a drop down box and clicks the update button that room will be displayed in that column until user decides to delete the column.

Comment: what if he choose the room and update. And then he revisits the page and as it is not saved in DB, he will never find the room he chose.

Comment: And if you are not going to save it anywhere and you don't need to hit the server to update the html table with the chosen room. Simply use jquery/javascript to update the column with selected value.:)

Comment: The things is if I was to save it to a DB wouldn't I have to create a relationship between the two tables with a foreign key constraint?  If so I really have no idea how to do that in ruby, which is way I was trying a different way.

Comment: So can you please update your question with the use-case. e.g A room can be assigned to one user or more?

Comment: I changed my table a little bit.  I've added a room number as another column.  But I don't want the student to be able to select the room number when they fill out the form, they can only select floor preference and admin can assign them a room number from the page that I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

button_tag creates a form on your page. The problem that you have right now is that the select_tag dropdown is not part of that form. What you probably want to do is to create the form explicitly and have the dropdown be inside of it. Replace your last 2 td's with something like this:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <% if student.floor_pref == '1st' %>
      <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@first_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% if student.floor_pref == '2nd' %>
      <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@second_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% if student.floor_pref == '3rd' %>
      <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@third_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
  <% end %>
  <td><%= submit_tag 'Update' %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Then your next step will be to customize the form so that you know which row it needs to affect. Your code as written will show the @selected_room as the same for each row.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I tried that the drop down box and update button disappeared

Comment: When you view source on your page, is there a form in that row where we're expecting it? If not, you might want to expand the form so that it includes the entire tr element.

Comment: Sorry. I missed having the '=' on the form_tag line. '<%' should be '<%='.

Comment: Hmm now when I hit the update button it takes me to the student form where students fill out their information and shows all the validation constraints that the fields are missing...  I just need it to add the selected room to the to that students record and then display it in that row.

Comment: You probably need to explicitly set the action where you want your form to land. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: Its landing at the right controller, but I think its trying to create new student each time I try do Update just the room number.  Why?  I have no clue...